# Google Cloud Endpoint Extensible Service Proxy does not start

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to install Extensible Service Proxy on my compute instance. I am following this guide for installing the ESP Nginx service: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine#running_the_extensible_service_proxy. I was able to install the ESP service without problems but when I try to start the service with the command service nginx start, the service does not start up.

First it gave this error in /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/sbin/start_esp.py", line 48, in <module>
from mako.template import Template
ImportError: No module named mako.template
```

The error went away after I installed the mako template module using the command pip install mako.

Now it is giving this error:

```
INFO:Fetching the service name from the metadata service
ERROR:Fetching service name failed (status code 404)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to put in your service name in your metadata?
From https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/quickstart-compute-engine:

In the Metadata section and add the following Endpoints metadata key/value pairs:

Specify endpoints-service-name as a key and YOUR-PROJECT-ID.appspot.com as its value, replacing YOUR-PROJECT-ID with your project ID.
Click Add item.
Specify endpoints-service-version as a key and the service version returned when you deployed as the key's value.

Comment: Yes. I added the metadata section, but it did not help. I had not installed the Google Cloud SDK. After I installed it, it gave this error:

    INFO:Fetching the service name from the metadata service
WARNING:Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2782af98d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 113] No route to host',)': /computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/endpoints-service-name
ERROR:Fetching service name failed (status code 404)

Comment: I had added the meta data to the general meta data section and not the meta data section for the virtual instance. After I added the meta data to the virtual instance, The ESP started working. Thanks